# What are the different runtimes in MLRun?

Tags: python, mlops, nuclio, mlrun

I'm trying to get a feel for how MLRun executes my Python code. What different runtimes are supported and why would I use one vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLRun has several different ways to run a piece of code. At this time, the following runtimes are supported:

- Batch runtimes

  - **local** - execute a Python or shell program in your local environment (i.e. Jupyter, IDE, etc.)
  - **job** - run the code in a Kubernetes Pod
  - **dask** - run the code as a Dask Distributed job (over Kubernetes)
  - **mpijob** - run distributed jobs and Horovod over the MPI job operator, used mainly for deep learning jobs
  - **spark** - run the job as a Spark job (using Spark Kubernetes Operator)
  - **remote-spark** - run the job on a remote Spark service/cluster (e.g. Iguazio Spark service)
- Real-time runtimes

  - **nuclio** - real-time serverless functions over Nuclio
  - **serving** - higher level real-time Graph (DAG) over one or more Nuclio functions

If you are interested in learning more about each runtime, see the [documentation](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/concepts/functions-overview.html).